# ¿Cómo contar cuántos valores distintos (column2) existen por referencia (column 1) en excel?

Tags: excel, office365, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

Tengo dos columnas en Excel. En la primera hay una lista de referencias de clientes. En la segunda son valores de transacción. Quisiera saber cuantas transacciones se realizaron por cliente.

Ejemplo:

```
Clients   |Value of trans.

    A     |  23
    B     |  24
    A     |  26
    C     |  24
    B     |  24
```

Quisiera algo como:

```
A | 2
B | 1
C | 1
```

Comment: Hay un artículo de Office sobre el tema: [Contar valores únicos entre duplicados](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Contar-valores-%C3%BAnicos-entre-duplicados-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES)

Answer (score 2):

## Una opción seria:

#### Paso 1 :Remover los duplicados

Seleccionamos nuestras dos columnas y vamos al menú de `Datos` y seleccionamos la opción `Quitar duplicados`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Paso 2: Usar una tabla dinamica

[Cómo crear una tabla dinámica](https://exceltotal.com/como-crear-una-tabla-dinamica/)

Como solo tienes dos columnas con valores, solo selecciona en la `etiqueta de fila` a tus clientes y en `Valores` selecciona **Value of trans.**

Y deberias tener algo como lo que necesitas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo:

1. Los datos se encuentran en el rango `B2:B7`
2. Los resultados se encuentran en el rango `E2:F7`

*Esta solución utiliza **`FormulaArrays`** que deben ser ingresadas presionando las teclas **`[Ctrl]` + `[Shift]` + `[Enter]`** simultáneamente. Podrá ver los símbolos **`{`** y **`}`** alrededor de la fórmula si se ha introducido correctamente.*

**Clients:** Introduzca esta *`FormulaArray`* en `E3` para extraer una lista de registros únicos de `Clients`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$2:$B$7, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( E$2:E2, $B$2:$B$7 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
```

Luego copie la celda `E3` al rango `E4:I7`

**Qty Trans.:** Introduzca esta fórmula en `F3` y copie celda `F3` hasta celda `F7`

```
=IF(EXACT(E3,""),"",COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,$E3))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Sugiero leer las siguientes páginas para obtener una comprensión más profunda de los recursos utilizados:*

[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188),

[Excel functions (by category)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5F91F4E9-7B42-46D2-9BD1-63F26A86C0EB),

[Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D),

[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7),

*Acepte mis disculpas por mostrar las formulas en la versión en inglés, ya que esa es la versión que tengo en mi máquina.
Igualmente las paginas sugeridas están en inglés, sugiero usar un navegador con traducción.*